# How to smoothly restrict/crop/bound a bent arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows

I am looking for a way to make an upwards bent TikZ arrow restricted by an upper bound if it "bumps against" it, i.e. it shall not exceed the invisible upper line but smoothly follow it (round corners). The challenge also consists in the two different cases:

1. *with bump*: the arrow actually bumps against the upper limit
   [image: with bump]
2. *without bump:* the arrow stays below the limit
   [image: without bump]

Remark: In my specific case, I have given two coordinate objects, but I cannot control the exact positions. I bent the arrow by `out` and `in` angle, see example.

**TeX example** in which an arrow exceeds the upper limit (dashed):
[image: failing example]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % two nodes that shall be connected via arrow
    \node[draw, circle] (A) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[draw, circle] (B) at (4, -0.1) {};
    
    % invisible bound to "bump" against
    \draw[dashed, red] (0, 0.3) -- (4, 0.3);
    
    % arrow that shall limited by the upper bound
    \draw[->] (B.north west) to [out=160,in=25] (A.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By use of the `max distance` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0pt}
                     ]
% two nodes that shall be connected via arrow
\node   (A) at (0, 0) {};
\node   (B) at (4, 0) {};

% invisible bound to "bump" against
\draw[dashed, red] (0, 0.3) -- (4, 0.3);

% arrow that shall limited by the upper bound
\draw[->] (B.north west) to [out=160,in=25] (A.north east);
\draw[blue, ->] (B.north west) to [out=160,in=25, 
                                   max distance=5mm]    % <---
                                        (A.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitively an awesome option!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am accepting this answer. It is not 100%ly what I specified, but it is incredibly simple and well-defined (in contrast to my question), and even better, it actually serves my use case. Still: I am eager to see further solutions to this problem. :)